# creating an new list based on set and another list

Tags: python-3.x

```
a=[inc123,inc353,inc345]
```

below three are sets:

```
{apple,inc123} {beery,inc345} {cheery,inc353}
```

B is expected output in the sequence of `a` with matching values in respective set

```
b=[apple,cheery,beery]
```

Comment: You should spend some time learning how to format things! You can use the `{}` icon in the toolbar for code. Get rid of everything in bold too.

Comment: Are those strings? You should quote them too. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
a=['inc123','inc353','inc345'] 
c= [{'apple','inc123'}, {'beery','inc345'}, {'cheery','inc353'}]
b = []
for ae in a:
    for ce in c:
        # Have to convert set to list as set would enumerate in random fashion
        # e.g.read in this sequence 'inc353' and 'cheery' if ce inside enumerate
        # instead of l
        l = list(ce) 
        f = None
        for i,e in enumerate(l):
            if i == 0:
                f = e
            else:
                if e == ae:
                    b.append(f)
print(b)
```

Someone may post a more elegant way with lambdas via filtering and mapping.

Take a look [here](https://medium.com/@happymishra66/lambda-map-and-filter-in-python-4935f248593) and have a play around.